# I am new to flutter, does anyone knows how to connect flutter sign up with firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I did the front end using flutter but I don't know how to connect it to the firebase auth. could someone please help in this? I just don't get the idea on how to connect my frontend with backend. this is my code:

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, avoid_unnecessary_containers, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, depend_on_referenced_packages, sized_box_for_whitespace

import 'package:booklub_2/Screens/Login/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:booklub_2/components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:booklub_2/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: w,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Sign up",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 50.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 25.0),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
            width: w,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(1, 1),
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                        )
                      ]),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Name',
                        hintText: 'Enter your name',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30))),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(1, 1),
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                        )
                      ]),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Username',
                      hintText: 'Enter your username',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.grey),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(1, 1),
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                        )
                      ]),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Email',
                        hintText: 'Enter your email',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30))),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(1, 1),
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                        )
                      ]),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Phone',
                      hintText: 'Enter your phone number',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.grey),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(1, 1),
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                        )
                      ]),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      hintText: 'Enter your password',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.grey),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(1, 1),
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                        )
                      ]),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Confirm Password',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.grey),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Forgot password',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40.0,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Roundedbutton(
              text: "SIGN UP",
              color: kPrimaryColor,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              press: () {},
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 110.0),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'New to BookLub ?',
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 5.0),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return LoginScreen();
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to follow so many resources but I am still confused regarding the backend of it.

Comment: please post a response if you got any after hit the login

Comment: I don't get anything

Comment: if you want something quick and dirty check out this package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_auth

Comment: @HunterBooks That package is the quickest is indeed the fastest way to add a UI for signing in to your Flutter app. I would hardly call it dirty though. ;-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you're right 

Answer (score 1):

[Flutter firebase authetication link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/)

please follow this documentation to understand the whole process

in a nutshell

1. First you have to configure the firebase properly
2. integrate the firebase with project properly
3. then follow the below code for signIn using email & password just for reference

   ```
   Future<User?> signIn(String email, String password) async {
   EasyLoading.show(status: "loading..");

   // firebase
   final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

   try {
     EasyLoading.dismiss();

     UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
         email: email, password: password);

     log(result.toString());

     User? user = result.user;

     log(user.toString());

     SharedPref.write(firebaseUid, user!.uid);

     var token = await user.getIdToken();

     SharedPref.write(firebaseAuthToken, token);

     if(user.emailVerified == false){

       user.sendEmailVerification();
       showMessage('Login Successful! Please verify your account by clicking on the link in the email sent to your registered mail',isError: false);

     }else{

       showMessage('Successfully Logged in!');
     }

     //EasyLoading.showSuccess('Successfully Logged in!');

     Timer(const Duration(seconds: 4), navigationPageHome);

     return Future.value(user);
   } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
     log(e.code);

     switch (e.code) {
       case 'invalid-email':
         EasyLoading.showError(e.code);
         break;
       case 'wrong-password':
         EasyLoading.showError(e.code);
         break;
       case 'user-not-found':
         EasyLoading.showError(e.code);
         break;
       case 'user-disabled':
         EasyLoading.showError(e.code);
         break;
     }
   }
   ```